# How to reset second drop down list if i change first drop down value?

Tags: flutter, api

I have two drop down which second is depends on first.

When i changing the first drop down value after selecting second dropdown value it throws an error as below.

[image]

So how to reset second drop down list if i changing first drop down value?

Drop down buttons are as below.

```
DropdownButtonFormField<Standard>(
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value == null) {
                          return "Select Standard";
                        }
                      },
                      isExpanded: true,
                      hint: Text('Select Standard'),
                      value: selectedStandard,
                      items: _standards.map((Standard standard) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<Standard>(
                          value: standard,
                          child: Text(standard.standardName),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                     
                      onChanged: (val) {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedStandard = val;
                          standardId = val?.standardId;
                          onMediumChange(val);
                        });
                      }),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),

                  DropdownButtonFormField<Medium>(
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value == null) {
                          return "Select Medium";
                        }
                      },
                      isExpanded: true,
                      hint: Text('Select Medium'),
                      value: selectedMedium,
                      items: _mediums.map((Medium medium) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<Medium>(
                          value: medium,
                          child: Text(medium.mediumName),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                     
                      onChanged: (val) {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedMedium = val;
                          mediumId = val?.mediumId;
                        });
                      }),
```

And get Values code is as below. Varibles which i used.

```
var _standards = <Standard>[];
  var _mediums = <Medium>[];
  Standard? selectedStandard;
  Medium? selectedMedium;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    ApiManager().getStandards().then((standards) {
      setState(() {
        _standards = standards;
      });
    });
  }

  void onMediumChange(standard) {
    setState(() {
      selectedStandard = standard;
      _mediums = [];
    });
    String mediumUrl =
        "$baseUrl/medium/get_by_course_id?standard_id=${selectedStandard?.standardId}";
    ApiManager().getMediums(mediumUrl).then((List<Medium> value) => {
          setState(() {
            _mediums = value;
          })
        });
  }
```

Comment: what i think is you just make the selectedMedium null when selecting the first dropdown item .If you still want better explanation please add  some sample data for this dropdowns so that i can create an example based on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand there is a problem with `selectedMedium`

Try change Make it selectedMedium `null` inside `onMediumChange`

```
 void onMediumChange(standard) {
setState(() {
  selectedMedium = null;
  selectedStandard = standard;
  _mediums = [];
});
String mediumUrl =
    "$baseUrl/medium/get_by_course_id?standard_id=${selectedStandard?.standardId}";
ApiManager().getMediums(mediumUrl).then((List<Medium> value) => {
      setState(() {
        _mediums = value;
      })
    });
```

}

Comment: variables which declared i can put by editing the question please check.

Comment: I didn't get what you saying. By assumption of what you saying you can edit the first setState inside the `onMediumChange(standard) ` to `_mediums.clear()`

Comment: Check now above solution, Also check whether new values are set inside `onMediumChange` method

Answer (score 0):

first, check the values in _mediums because you must have a different value of selectedMedium here as according to this error !!!

Comment: can you please give example or write the code?

Comment: @DhavalChaudhari The error says that you're passing null into DropdownMenuItem. It means that when you change item in first dropdown, you're setting empty list for second drop down by _mediums = []. Which is causing error. Can you try by passing _mediums = [""] and see what happens.